# Python: Issues downloading file from google drive api, getting daily limit for unauthenticated use exceeded

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

**Problem Statement:**

I am being plagued with a single issue when trying to download a file from the google drive api for my python app. I just started working with it today so I am probably doing something stupid so bear with me :).

The issue I am getting is that after authenticating my app with the drive-api, I can read files and metadata from google drive but I can't download them. The relevant code is posted below for reference.

**Steps Followed:**

I first followed the directions to enable OAuth2, and get the credentials.json/client_secrets.json. I made sure that the scope was correct in terms of the permissions and then generated my pickle file. From there, I used the code from the docs and quickstart guides to make my code. From there, I couldn't make any progress. I thought that I might have to require a security assessment for my app but I am not planning on publishing it so I thought this level of permissions would be fine for developers.
I see many other stack overflow posts about this but I am not getting anything helpful (I thought I followed all the same steps to authenticate and enable drive-api permissions for my app).

I also haven't been able to download a single file yet so I don't think I am hitting the daily limits. I think I am not doing the request authentication correctly but I can't find any documentation on that. I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

**Reference Code:**

All the code I have is taken straight from the docs. Here are the relevant links:

1. authorization & list files: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python
2. download files: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads
3. delete_file: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete#auth

Here is the initialization code:

```
# packages
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from apiclient import errors
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'] # set permisions to read/write/delete
creds = None
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
             'client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

And here is my drive download function:

```
def download_from_drive_to_local(drive, fname):
    # search for image in drive
    file_search = drive.files().list(
        q=f"name = '{fname}'", 
        spaces='drive', 
        fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = file_search.get('files', [])
    print('Files retrieved: ', items)
    
    # download retrieved image from drive
    item_ids = [i['id'] for i in items]
    if len(item_ids) > 1: print("Warning: multiple files exist with the same name. Using first file found.")
    for i in items:
        request = drive.files().get_media(fileId=i)
        fh = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        break

    # delete retrieved image from drive
    for i in items:
        try:
            drive.files().delete(fileId=i).execute()
        except errors.HttpError as error:
            print(f'An error occured deleting file id <{i}>: {error}.')
    # write bytearray to file
    with open(os.path.join(self.download_dir, f'{fname}.tif'), 'wb') as file: file.write(fh)
```

And my erroneous result:
[image: notebook error]

Clicking the link gives me this:
[image: daily_limit_exceeded_error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, I thought that `items` of `for i in items:` is from `items = file_search.get('files', [])`. In this case, `i` is like `{'name': '###', 'id': '###'}`. And when this is used as `i` of `request = drive.files().get_media(fileId=i)`, the file is is used as `{'name': '###', 'id': '###'}`. I thought that this is the reason of your issue.
- And, when you want to save the downloaded data as a file using `fh = io.BytesIO()`, the script for saving it is as follows.

  ```
    with io.open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        fh.seek(0)
        f.write(fh.read())
  ```
- When the length of `item_ids` is `0`, an error occurs.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
# download retrieved image from drive
item_ids = [i['id'] for i in items]
if len(item_ids) > 1: print("Warning: multiple files exist with the same name. Using first file found.")
for i in items:
    request = drive.files().get_media(fileId=i)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    break

# delete retrieved image from drive
for i in items:
    try:
        drive.files().delete(fileId=i).execute()
    except errors.HttpError as error:
        print(f'An error occured deleting file id <{i}>: {error}.')
# write bytearray to file
with open(os.path.join(self.download_dir, f'{fname}.tif'), 'wb') as file: file.write(fh)
```

To:

```
# download retrieved image from drive
item_ids = [i['id'] for i in items]
if len(item_ids) > 1:
    print("Warning: multiple files exist with the same name. Using first file found.")
for i in item_ids:
    request = drive.files().get_media(fileId=i)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    break

# delete retrieved image from drive
for i in item_ids:
    try:
        drive.files().delete(fileId=i).execute()
    except errors.HttpError as error:
        print(f'An error occured deleting file id <{i}>: {error}.')

# write bytearray to file
if item_ids != []:
    with io.open(os.path.join(self.download_dir, f'{fname}.tif'), 'wb') as f:
        fh.seek(0)
        f.write(fh.read())
```

Comment: Just as a follow-up, I see that my problem wasn't quite with the google drive API but with my own script, I guess I could have gleaned the problem from reading the error more carefully. However, do you know why google sends you a 403 with the 'daily limit reached' message along with the failure reason? It almost seems misleading... thanks for your help!

Comment: @Varun Govind Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the situation. So I cannot tell you the clear answer. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But when I could correctly understand about the situation, I would like to think of the reason. In order to understand various situations, I have to study more and more. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: @Varun Govind About the error of `dailyLimitExceededUnreg` by clicking the URL of `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{'name': '###', 'id': '##'}?alt=media` in the error message, in this case, the URL is for downloading the file. In this case, it is required to use the access token and API key (when the file is publicly shared). But when you just click the URL, these are not used. I thought that this is the reason of the error of `dailyLimitExceededUnreg`. But if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.